# How are PlayFramework, Ebean and HickariCP all connected?

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I am using Ebean with Play 2.4, but I am not clear on how the connections to JDBC pool are handled. Currently I just create a EbeanServer and make requests to the Database with that.

Can someone throw some light on this topic. How is PlayFramework, Ebean and HickariCP all connected ? Do I need to configure anything? Do I need to be worried about taking this setup to production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Play Framework

Play Framework is the framework you are using to develop your applications. Almost all applications would need some sort of data storage and this is provided (in most cases) by a database.

### Connection pools

Now, in order to access this database, you would need to retrieve connections and then work with these connections - perform `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and so on. Nobody stops you from managing all this by yourself. But there are some guys who have better knowledge on the topic and they have created the so-called **connection pool** (CP) implementations - these are libraries which do most of the dirty work for you - they care about getting a valid connection, they care about managing a pool of 'ready-to-go' connections so that you don't lose time, they care about closing the database connections properly and so on. Most of the time you don't really interact directly with the connection pool implementation. This is the case because as a developer you work on a higher level.

There are different CP implementations - [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), [BoneCP](http://www.jolbox.com/), [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) and so on. The default one in Play Framework 2.4 is HikariCP, the one in 2.3 was BoneCP.

### ORM

As with the database connections, when working with some models and save / retrieve them from the database, you don't want to work on low level stuff. You want to have some abstractions.

In your application you have modeled something - let's say an online store - you have Products, Orders, Customers and so on. You have written some Java/Scala classes which represent these entities - `Product.java` with some fields, `Order.java` with some fields and so on. Now if you have a relational database (think PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL, etc.) you know that you have tables with rows and columns. So in order to save your data, you would need to ***map*** it to this table-based structure. This is where ORM implementations come into play. ORM is an abbreviation for object-relational mapping. This is like a blueprint of how each of your classes and fields corresponds to tables and columns.

As with the connection pools, there are different ORM implementations - [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), [Ebean](http://ebean-orm.github.io/) and so on. Ebean was kind of the default one in previous Play versions.

---

It just happens that Play Framework comes with some defaults. You are totally free to exchange almost anything in Play - you can even change the templating engine. The good thing is that these are sane defaults - if you want to build something without much fooling around - just start with the default choices. If you architect all properly, the effort to replace specific implementations should be minimal.

---

Last note on production setup: without proper measures and without knowing much about your use cases, nobody can say if the production performance would be good. You can read more about tweaking the JDBC side of Play here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsJDBC

I hope this gives some overview of the relations between Play, HikariCP and Ebean.